# How exacly is MPI launching so many proccesse

Tags: c, parallel-processing, compilation, mpi, mpich

I've recently started running MPI on my computer for some practice, after having some experience using MPI on a cluster. I have a dual core processor but was curious about what would happen if I specified a large number of processes and to my surprise it worked.

mpirun -np 40 ./wha

How exactly is this happening. Even considering the number of threads a single one of the processors could spawn this doesn't seem possible.

Comment: It might not be the most efficient choice for computation, but take a look at how many processes are running on your computer at any given time.

Comment: They are running concurrently but not running in **parallel**.

Comment: You end up doing time sharing when what you need is true parallelism in order to achieve greater performance.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala what exactly do you mean by concurrently but not in parallel

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Makes sense and i figured as much. Do you have any links or articles I can follow up with to get an in-depth idea of whats going on here. Much appreciated.

Comment: Running more MPI tasks than available slots is called **oversubscription**. I do not have any link, but I guess google has some with this keyword.

Answer (score 0):

In case of OpenMPI, if the number of processes running is larger than the number of processors (i.e when Oversubscription happens), OpenMPI starts running the MPI processes in **degraded** mode. Running in degraded mode means yielding it's processor to other MPI processes for making progress (i.e time sharing happens). `mpi_yield_when_idle` can be set to 0 for making the mode **aggressive** explicitly, in such case the MPI process won't give the processor to other processes voluntarily.

See [here](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=running#oversubscribing)